# How is caffe input_shape actually work?

Tags: caffe

I'm confused about the followinng block in a caffe implemented prj of obj detection with Faster-RCNN in the begining of test.prototxt:

```
input: "data"
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 3
  dim: 224
  dim: 224
}

input: "im_info"
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 3
}
```

but actually the input is not the specified size of 224*224, and does not need to be 224*224, I see in the test code, images are just read with out resize and then pass through the network, very confused, and did not find reference of how caffe define these blocks, can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the input shape is not determined by the terms here:

```
input: "data"
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 3
  dim: 224
  dim: 224
}

input: "im_info"
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 3
}
```

after I change input dim to arbitrary size, like 424:

```
input: "data"
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 3
  dim: 424
  dim: 424
}

input: "im_info"
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 3
}
```

the test AP does not change a bit, indicates there is some modification done so that image size is not determined here by the `input_shape` in `test.prototxt`, then I dive into the code, found lines here:

```
net.blobs['data'].reshape(*(blobs['data'].shape))
```

before the :

```
forward_kwargs = {'data': blobs['data'].astype(np.float32, copy=False)}
if cfg.TEST.HAS_RPN:
    forward_kwargs['im_info'] = blobs['im_info'].astype(np.float32, copy=False)
else:
    forward_kwargs['rois'] = blobs['rois'].astype(np.float32, copy=False)
blobs_out = net.forward(**forward_kwargs)
```

and the blobs['data'].shape is the size of input image with resize process so that the width is 600:(I don't post all lines here)

```
im_scale = float(cfg.TEST.MAX_SIZE) / float(im_size_max)
im = cv2.resize(im_orig, None, None, fx=im_scale, fy=im_scale,
                        interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```